# Drawdown formula Script on Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet that capture the Google form answers starting from column B . In column A I want to have a "status" column which every new form submitted will populate the related row on column A with the value "New application". That value on column A will then be replaced manually with the relevant status option that should be part of a dropdown (data validation).
I've tried using array and even different scripts founded in the web, but every time I change manually the status from one of the existing lines it messes up the other rows.
Is it possible to make something like this on Google sheets? Does someone have any suggestions?

I tried array formulas and scripts

Comment: I'm assuming you want to add the submittal after the last row of the sheet?  And this runs from your onFormSubmitt trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, sharing so if someone need to solve the same type of issue can be useful.
I used the following script:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  
  // Check if the submitted form has a value in column C
  if (e.values[2]) {
    // Set "New Application" in the corresponding row in column A
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).setValue("New Application");
  }
}
```